# Need to run for loop and WaitFor in sync CasperJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs, synchronous, casperjs

I have a code as below

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.on('remote.message', function (msg) {
    this.echo(msg);
});



casper.start( << some url >> , function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());


});
var resultObj = [];
casper.thenClick("#AddToCart").then(function () {
    // scrape something else

    casper.options.waitTimeout = 100000;

    var objectOne = this.evaluate(someFunction, << variables >> );
    //above function returns object
    casper.each(objectOne, function (self, obj) {



        var anotherObject = this.evaluate(anotherFunction, << variables >> );

        self.waitFor(function check() {

            var result = this.evaluate(thirdFunction, obj);
            if (result != 'no') {
                resultObj.push(result);


            }

            //  result = 'yes';
            return result != 'no';
            this.evaluate(function () {});
        }, function then() {


            console.log('done')


        });


    });
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.exit();
});
```

It contains a loop (.each) followed by wait for. The problem that I am facing is the loop gets executed completely and then waitFor gets executed.
How can I achieve them to be in sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you will want to use `casper.eachThen()` instead of `casper.each()`.

Warning: you will need at the very least, CasperJS 1.1-beta1 in order to run this.

I wasn't able to get much out of your code, but it looks like you may also want to change a few of your `casper.evaluate()` to `casper.thenEvaluate()`

I added `// ---` around the code that I modified below. Hope it helps.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.on('remote.message', function (msg) {
    this.echo(msg);
});

casper.start( << some url >> , function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
var resultObj = [];
casper.thenClick("#AddToCart").then(function () {
    // scrape something else

    casper.options.waitTimeout = 100000;

    var objectOne = this.evaluate(someFunction, << variables >> );
    //above function returns object

    // ---
    casper.eachThen(objectOne, function (response) {
    // ---

        var anotherObject = this.evaluate(anotherFunction, << variables >> );

        this.waitFor(function check() {
            // ---
            var result = this.evaluate(thirdFunction, response.data);
            // ---

            if (result != 'no') {
                resultObj.push(result);
            }

            //  result = 'yes';
            return result != 'no';
            this.evaluate(function () {});
        }, function then() {
            console.log('done')
        });


    });
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.exit();
});
```